# Script using CURL to add information to site every month

Tags: bash, curl

I am very new at bash, so forgive me for the novice question.

Here is my curl call:

```
curl -d 'username=cdaniels&wallclock=391324502' 'https://www-dev.***.***.edu/clusterusage/rest/update.html';
```

which pulls from a file `~/qacct.monthly` with the format

```
Total    : OWNER         WALLCLOCK         UTIME         STIME           CPU             MEMORY                 IO                IOW
Total    : ==========================================================================================================================
Total    : cdaniels      391324502         0.195         0.066         0.261              0.000              0.007              0.000
Total    : jlinger               1         0.039         0.056         0.095              0.000              0.000              0.000
Total    : lbsome         18707336  18675574.761     21433.535  18697008.296       10604793.658           5527.986              0.000
```

The example only pulls one of the users, but I want it to parse through the information and pull all the usernames and wallclock information from all the users on the cluster for that month.

I'm wanting to put this into a script so that it executes every month (obviously through a cron job)

Comment: I was thinking something like this: ~/qacct.monthly | awk '{print $3}''{print $4}' : which yields the username and wallclock information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r data; do
    curl -d "${data}" 'https://www-dev.***.***.edu/clusterusage/rest/update.html'
done < <(awk 'NR>2 { print "username="$3"&wallclock="$4 }' users)
```

Comment: I keep getting an error:                            line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
curl_sysadmin.sh: line 7: `done < <(awk 'NR>2 { print "username=$3"&wallclock="$4 }' users)'

Comment: @Jeff - Sorry, wrong interpreter.